# Error: Unable to load celery application. The module main was not found. Supervisor + celery

Tags: celery, supervisord

I can’t start a bunch supervisor and celery. Because celery does not see my module app.

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf**

```
[program:celery]

command=/home/ubuntu/django/.env/bin/celery -A main worker --app=main --loglevel=info
user=root
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/django/deployment/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/django/deployment/logs/celery_main.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
```

```
-django
 --.env
 --main
   ---settings.py
   ---celery.py
   ...
 --orders
 --shop
```

if I run this command in a virtual environment in my project directory everything works fine. But if I want to do it at a distance I can not, Why? In my logs celery says `Error: Unable to load celery application. The module main was not found.`

Comment: You have name app `celery` in your project?

Comment: Tell me in which python file you create Celery object, and what is its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I don't see in your configuration file is the working directory, that could explain why the celery command can not find the module, but it is working when you run it manually.

Try adding:

```
directory=/home/ubuntu/django
```

to your configuration file and see if this will fix the error.